# ¿Como dibujar una imagen Ovalada en un JLabel Usando Graphics?

Tags: java

El detalle de mi problema es que necesito dibujar una imagen ovalada en un JLabel,
no tengo mucha experiencia en **Graphics** asta ahorita esto es lo que tengo, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
class imagePanel extends JLabel {

    private BufferedImage buffImage = null;

    private void drawFingerImage(int nWidth, int nHeight, byte[] buff) {
        buffImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        buffImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, buff);
        Graphics g = buffImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, 140, 150, null);
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

[image: Esto es lo que tengo]

Comment: Hola Miguel. ¿Te refieres a que el contenido de la imagen esté dentro del círculo en lugar de tener ese marco rectangular?

Comment: Así es, para que sea mas estilizada la imagen, ya que esa imagen la obtengo desde un lector de huellas

Comment: Mi idea es primero cargar la imagen que va dentro del círculo, luego cargar la imagen que sirve de contorno, ambas sobre un mismo buffer de memoria para la imagen, y luego todo esto junto pintarlo en un segundo buffer donde se encuentre listo para mostrarlo. Para esto, debes considerar que la imagen del borde tiene el centro con color transparente (no blanco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la respuesta a esta pregunta era muy sencilla.

g.setClip(new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float(0f, 0f, 210, 200));

```
class imagePanel extends JLabel {

private BufferedImage buffImage = null;

private void drawFingerImage(int nWidth, int nHeight, byte[] buff) {
    buffImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    buffImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, buff);
    Graphics g = buffImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, 140, 150, null);
    g.dispose();
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //Aquí se agrega la línea
    g.setClip(new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float(0f, 0f, 210, 200));
    g.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

}

Ya con ese metodo se hace redonda la imagen de la huella